# Equilibrium position of $ n $ free charges as polynomials roots

Tags: polynomials, mp.mathematical-physics, orthogonal-polynomials

I asked the same question on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701220/equilibrium-position-of-n-free-charges-as-polynomials-roots) but received no answer.

The classic problem of the electrostatic equilibrium positions of a linear system of $ n $ free unit charges between two fixed charges is well known, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/350628/) an example with $n = 1$.

Few days ago I found out a nice result going back to Stieltjes and Hasse: if the potential between the two fixed charges is logarithmic, then the positions mentioned above can be computed as the roots of the Jacobi polynomial $P_{n}^{(2p-1,2q-1)}$, where $p$ is the fixed charge positioned in position $-1$,
$q$ is  is the fixed charge in position $+1$ and $n$ is the number of free unit charges (I attached an extract from Szego's book "Orthogonal polynomials").

My question is if there exist anything similar for the Coulomb potential  $V=1/r$. I found some reference at the end of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(98)00156-3), but I would know more.

[image]

Comment: Where did you ask the same question? Your link goes to a picture.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, just edited

Comment: Not entirely sure how related this is: there is an extension of the Stieltjes result to the six classical orthogonal polynomials that has a 1/r interaction between roots (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09697.pdf). The induced energy can be used to quickly find roots of the six classical orthogonal polynomials by solving a coupled system of ODEs (faster methods exist, of course).